# MSB3644 error when building with .net 5.0

Tags: .net, msbuild

After installing .net 5.0 dotnet-cli works, but after creating new project `dotnet build` fails with error `error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework “.NETFramework,Version=v5.0” were not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the environment variable `MSBuildSdksPath` equals `<dotnet install path>\sdk\5.0.100-preview.3.20216.6\Sdks`