# How to solve the Error MSB3644 in Visual Studio 2019 com. edition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I have a dev machine with

- Windows 10 version 1909 (build 18363.1016)
- Visual Studio Community edition 2019 version 16.7.2
- .net plataform sdk 5.0.100-preview.5.20279.10 (and olders)

I install net plataform sdk 5.0 to run Fluid UI Desktop apps (using C#). When i create and run a blank template project, i got the error MSB3644

> Error MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks  WinUIdesktop2   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   1177

On my comand line i checked the plataform SDK installed using **dotnet --list-sdks**

```
C:\Users\my_profile>dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.802 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.100-preview.5.20279.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

C:\Users\my_profile>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I am suffering from same problem. Thank you for raising this.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268779/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-netcore-version-v5-0-were-not-found relevant? I know it's .NET Core, but still.

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745089/msb3644-error-when-building-with-net-5-0

Comment: @AKX .NET 5.0 *is* the next .NET Core version

Comment: `.net plataform sdk 5.0.100-preview.5.20279.10 (and olders)` that's a very old version. The latest one is Preview 8, released today. That version is supported by the latest Preview version of Visual Studio, 16.8 Preview 2. Update to the latest versions for both. It's quite likely you've encountered problems that were fixed in later previews

Comment: In fact, it's quite possible that the VS and SDK version don't work with each other. A *release* version of Visual Studio typically doesn't support Preview versions of the SDK

Comment: BTW Preview 8 is feature complete, which means it's a far better target than Preview 5. It's not Go-Live yet, that's for the RC version expected next month but all planned features are already included. Any changes should involve bug fixes only

Comment: @KlausGütter This question was about `.NETFramework,Version=v5.0`, not .NET Core :)

Comment: @AKX AFAIK, there is no such thing as ".NET Framework 5.0", there is ".NET 5.0" which is technically the successor of .NET Core 3.x

Comment: you have to use [16.8 preview to use .net 5.0 previews](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/5.0/preview/5.0.0-preview.8.md#visual-studio-compatibility) or in option select usage of preview SDK, but I have no idea if it works.

Comment: please provide your csproj as a [mcve]

Comment: @magicandre1981 has the answer, you should post it as an answer

Comment: I am updating the windows 10 to version 2004. The stackoverflow article about the references is related to visual studio 2017 and  my problem is that the templates give errors out of the box.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Microsoft states that you need a 16.8 preview](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/5.0/preview/5.0.0-preview.8.md#visual-studio-compatibility) version to use .net 5.0, in case of .NET 5 Preview 8 you need Visual Studio 2019 16.8 Preview 2:

> .NET 5 Preview 8 requires Visual Studio 2019 16.8 Preview 2 to take
> full advantage of all its features. .NET 5 Preview 8 won't work
> properly in earlier versions of Visual Studio.

You use 16.7.2 so it is not compatible.

Comment: This should be the selected answer! Thank you @magiccandre1981

Comment: Using Jetbrains Rider I think I also just need an update.

Comment: @Urasquirrel looks like you need at least [Rider 2020.3](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012728920-Support-for-the-NET-SDK-5-0)

Comment: Yes that was the solution for me!

Answer (score -1):

You must update your Visual Studio 2019 version to be able to use .Net 5. Must be at least 16.8

Comment: Hi Tank, the other answer already covered this information almost a year ago.